# How to break out of While SqlDataReader.Read loop to return value and then return to current place in loop

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, return, sqldatareader

I am reading values from a query with the sqldatareader. I have a conditional statement inside the while loop that changes a string variable that is called by a hyperlink text databind in a listview. My trouble is that, for each row that the sqldatareader.read reads in, I need to bind the value of my variable "name" to the hyperlink. But, every time that I return out of the while loop, the reader starts over on the first line. I need to be able to return out of the while loop to pass the value of the variable and then continue back in the loop on the next row. Say in total, the datareader will read in 8 rows, right now it just reads the first row value 8 times. If this isn't possible could you provide me with some type of work around to this problem? Here is my code

```
 Conn.Open()
        sql4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", Search)
        sql4.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct Category, Type FROM SubCategory  WHERE (Subcategory.Category LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')"
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql4.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()

            Dim tst As String = reader("Category")

            If reader.IsDBNull(1) Then

                name = "Category"
                Return name

            ElseIf Not reader.IsDBNull(1) Then

                name = "Type"
                Return name

            End If
        End While
```

Comment: If you return from a loop you should not need to go back. Maybe you should use a `DataSource` for the `ListView`, maybe you should return a `DataTable` and access that row per row. But you have not provided enough informations to help.

Comment: well my thing is, this code is in a function that gets called from my Listview. Since the listView is also databound, the listview calls this function for every row created. If there were 10 total values returned by the query the listview would call my function 10 times. Therefore I need to be able to return out of the while loop to send the value of "name" which is evaluated by the first row returned by the query to the listview then return the while loop listed above except evaluate the next row

Comment: You should store the values in a list and then use the list for your logic.

Comment: @user3841709: why are these values not included (f.e. as JOIN) in the original select which is bound to the `ListView`? As workaround: you could load this into a `DataTable` once before you need it for every row and access it f.e. via LINQ.

Comment: Bc The query used in the code above is strictly to evaluate two columns for NULL values and based on if the value is null in column "type" i set the name variable.

Comment: Like Tim said, this could definetly be return in the original select.

Comment: I will have to try but i'm not sure if it will work with my original select because the formviews original select is to only show the values from "Category" on a formview. The reason that I need to be able to show both "Category" and "Type" now is that it is loading a search textbox value and querying based on that. However, the original must stay the same where unless there is a search query it will only show "Category".

Comment: I am playing around with it now though to see if I can figure out how to put this in the original

Comment: I got it figured out guys, thanks. You all were right except it's in a separate query besides the two we were discussing but I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the suggestions that I should be able to do it in the query being called by the ListView. I just ended up creating a new column when the select query is run with a conditional statement that evaluates if the "Type" column is null or not, Then I just databind to my new column for the hyperlink text. here is the piece of code.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Photos.Picture, SubCategory.Category, SubCategory.Type, CASE WHEN SubCategory.Type IS NULL THEN SubCategory.Category ELSE SubCategory.Type END AS linkText FROM SubCategory LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos ON SubCategory.Type = Photos.Type WHERE (SubCategory.Type LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')
```

Thanks again guys.